# XML parse selected elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery, xml-parsing

I nee a little bit of help in parsing my XML. The XML is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <game title="Dementia">
            <cat>
                <catTitle>Mild</catTitle>
                <item>mild-1</item>
                <item>mild-2</item>
                <item>mild-3</item>
            </cat>
            <cat>
                <catTitle>Moderate</catTitle>
                <item>Moderate-1</item>
                <item>Moderate-2</item>
                <item>Moderate-3</item>
            </cat>
            <cat>
                <catTitle>Severe</catTitle>
                <item>Severe-1</item>
                <item>Severe-2</item>
            </cat>
    </game>

    <game title="Risks">
        <cat>
            <catTitle>Low</catTitle>
            <item>Low-1</item>
            <item>Low-2</item>
            <item>Low-3</item>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <catTitle>Medium</catTitle>
            <item>Medium-1</item>
            <item>Medium-2</item>
            <item>Medium-3</item>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <catTitle>High</catTitle>
            <item>High-1</item>
            <item>High-2</item>
        </cat>
    </game>

</config>
```

As you can see in this config file there are two "Games". Each has their own title attribute. I have managed to select these attributes and add them to a drop down menu from which the user selects which game they want to play.

My problem is that currently when I parse the document, it parses through both games, rather than just the one that I want.

At the moment my code is:

```
$(xml).find("cat").each(function(idx, v) {
        categoryArrays[idx] = [];

        $(v).find("catTitle").each(function(){

            //$(xml).find('title:contains("Dimentia")').each(function(){
            numberofCategories = numberofCategories+1;
            tmpCategory = $(this).text();
            categoryNames.push(tmpCategory);


            var $cat = $('<div id=catPileBox>' +
                            '<div class="catPileBoxTitle font">' + tmpCategory + '</div>' +
                            '<div class="catPileBoxBody font"> </div>' +
                        '</div>')
                    .fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#catPile').attr('categoryName', tmpCategory).attr('categoryNum', idx).droppable({
                containment: '#content',
                stack: '#catPileBox',
                cursor: 'move',
                drop: handleDropEvent
            });
        });



        //ITEM PARSING
            $(v).find("item").each(function( i , vi) {
                categoryArrays[idx].push( $(vi).text() );

                numberofItems = numberofItems+1;
                tmpItem = $(this).text();

                //Add Item to Array
                itemNames.push(tmpItem);

                       //UI CREATION and Atrribute setting
                        var $item = //$('<div id=itemPileBox div class=font >' + tmpItem + '</div>')


                $('<div id=itemPileBox>' +
                        '<div class="itemPileBoxPic"><img src="icon.jpg"></div>'+
                        '<div class="itemPileBoxTitle font">' + tmpItem + '</div>' +
                        '<div class="itemPileBoxBody font">Having a fit and going mental</div>' +
                        '</div>')

                                .fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#itemPile').attr('itemName', tmpItem).attr('categoryNum', categoryArrayNum).draggable({
                            containment: '#content',
                            stack: '#itemPileBox',
                            cursor: 'move',
                            revert: true
                        });

                        console.log("Item Created: " + tmpItem + " // Item's Category:" + categoryArrayNum) ;

            });


        console.log('-- Category Array Num: ' + categoryArrayNum + ' contains: ' + categoryArrays[categoryArrayNum]);
        categoryArrayNum++;
        });

      $(shuffleItems());
      console.log("// ITEMS ASSIGNED TO CATEGORIES");

    }
```

I understand that at the start I will need to add something to do with find the game attribute where title matches that selected in the combo box.

*If someone could just tell me how I can select or selectively parse just the part of the document where "game title=Dementia" and ignore any other game(and their children) I can change all the variables to match those in the combobox myself..*

**Thanks for your time, and thanks in advance!**

Comment: where is `xml` coming from, has it been parsed to an xml document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML('<?xml version="1.0"?><config>     <game title="Dementia">             <cat>                 <catTitle>Mild</catTitle>                 <item>mild-1</item>                 <item>mild-2</item>                 <item>mild-3</item>             </cat>             <cat>                 <catTitle>Moderate</catTitle>                 <item>Moderate-1</item>                 <item>Moderate-2</item>                 <item>Moderate-3</item>             </cat>             <cat>                 <catTitle>Severe</catTitle>                 <item>Severe-1</item>                 <item>Severe-2</item>             </cat>     </game>      <game title="Risks">         <cat>             <catTitle>Low</catTitle>             <item>Low-1</item>             <item>Low-2</item>             <item>Low-3</item>         </cat>         <cat>             <catTitle>Medium</catTitle>             <item>Medium-1</item>             <item>Medium-2</item>             <item>Medium-3</item>         </cat>         <cat>             <catTitle>High</catTitle>             <item>High-1</item>             <item>High-2</item>         </cat>     </game>  </config>' )
console.log($(xmlDoc ).find("game[title=Dementia]"))​
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6M5Uh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an XMLDoc, you could do this:

```
$(xml).find("game[title=Dementia] cat").each(...
```

to get all `cat` elements under `game` elements that have the title `Dementia`.